# How do I get rate and configuration values?

Tags: commerce, 9

I'm stumped. How do you get values off of the shipment method config? For example I have a the Flat Rate shipping method "Express". I want to get the raw config form values stored on that shipping method. Such as rate, or a custom field I've provided.

I've plugged into the shipping methods to add a custom form field. But now need to retrieve it later on. The values aren't on the shipment entity.

```
    $shippingMethodId = $commerceOrder->shipments->entity->shipping_method->entity->shipping_method_id->value;
    $shipping_method_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_shipping_method');
    $shipping_method = $shipping_method_storage->load($shippingMethodId);
    //$shipping_method->rate->value
    //$shipping_method->honeys_place_shipping_code->value
```

I've tried appending the values to the ShippingRate returned from calculateRates()

```
public function calculateRates(ShipmentInterface $shipment) {
    $rates = [];
    $rates[] = new ShippingRate([
      'shipping_method_id' => $this->parentEntity->id(),
      'service' => $this->services['default'],
      'amount' => Price::fromArray($this->configuration['rate_amount']),
      'description' => $this->configuration['rate_description'],
      'honeys_place_shipping_code' => $this->configuration['honeys_place_shipping_code'] // < -----
    ]);

    return $rates;
  }
```

This fires but does not make it into the shipment entity on the order later. I know I can retrieve the rate by accessing 'amount' off of the shipment entity. But I also need to retrieve custom values.

Is there a way to retrieve these values from config or get them onto the shipment entity object?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$shippingMethodId = $commerceOrder->shipments->entity->shipping_method->entity->shipping_method_id->value;
$shipping_method_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_shipping_method');
$shipping_method = $shipping_method_storage->load($shippingMethodId);

$rate = $shipping_method->plugin->getValue()[0]['target_plugin_configuration']['rate_amount'];
```

You'll have to dig deeper on the plugin field from the shipping_method entity.

```
$shipping_method->plugin->getValue()[0];
// This will return the following array below
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful thanks. I didn't think to look there.